# Cartoon Network show with three main characters who battle with cards

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have been searching for ages and ages. But can’t find anything, so does anyone remember a show on Cartoon Network (I think it was, but I’m not sure) where there were 3 main characters and they used cards or something to get powers? One of them was a girl with blue hair and another, I think, was a boy with blonde hair. But the other boy (I think his hair was brown) was like the leader of the trio. And there was this villain that was the blue-haired girl's father. I think her name was like Nya or Mia Idek.

But it was around the same time period as the 2004 *Ben 10* and I thought I remembered the name, but there is no trace of it.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216075/2010s-cartoon-three-teens-have-the-power-to-control-monsters-to-fight-other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *[Redakai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series))* (2011).

Teens using battling cards that tied in with a merchandise game. Main female character is Maya. Lokar (the villain) turns out to be

> Maya's grandfather.